# Preventing components below panel to get hovered when panel is transparent

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, transparency

I have a `JPanel`, set to be transparent:

```
public SomePanel() {
    setOpaque(false);
    [...]
}
```

I have other `JComponent` instances under it (at the same location, but below it).

If I draw on the panel using `paintComponent(g)`, putting my mouse on the panel still triggers `mouseEntered` and `mouseExited` events for other components below it.

How can I prevent components below the panel to fire mouse events if the non-opaque panel is visible? I am using `setOpaque(false)` because I need a transparent background, perhaps there is another way to achieve this?

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: What happens if you give the covering JPanel a MouseListener of its own, one that will swallow mouse events?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Yes that fixes it, please post an answer ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution: give the covering JPanel its own MouseListener, one that is there to simply swallow the mouse events and prevent them from being transmitted. The code could be as simple as:

```
myPanel.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {});
```